# Data Science for Social Good

Tags: machine-learning, community

I'm interested in doing a mapping or inventory of all data science for social good and technology for social good organizations/initivaives. Is anyone aware of any similar efforts or places to start?

Comment: Yes: http://www.datakind.org

Comment: There was a workshop for this exact topic at ECML last year. [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/ecmlpkdd2016sogood/accepted-papers)'s a list of the proceedings

Answer (score 2):

Sources that I've found so far;

1. [datakind](http://www.datakind.org/)
2. [Data4Democracy](https://github.com/Data4Democracy)
3. [Data Science for Social Good](https://dssg.uchicago.edu/projects/)
4. [eScience DSSG projects](http://escience.washington.edu/dssg/project-summaries-2016/)

Other ideas: find a set of data that interests you depending on where you live for example and contribute to your community. Things like [data.gov](https://www.data.gov/) in US and [open-data](http://open.canada.ca/en/open-data) in Canada.